# Get the last inserted row ID in trafodion

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I want to get the row ID or record ID for last inserted record in the table in Trafodion.

Example:

```
1 | John <br/>
2 | Michael
```

When executing an INSERT statement, I want to return the created ID, means 3.

Could anyone tell me how to do that using trafodion or is it not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a sequence generator to generate unique ids for this table? Something like this:

```
create table idcol (a largeint generated always as identity not null,
                    b int,
                    primary key(a desc));
```

Either way, with or without sequence generator, you could get the highest key with this statement:

```
select max(a) from idcol;
```

The problem is that this statement could be very inefficient. Trafodion has a built-in optimization to read the min of a key column, but it doesn't use the same optimization for the max value, because HBase didn't have a reverse scan until recently. We should make use of the reverse scan, please feel free to file a JIRA. To make this more efficient with the current code, I added a **DESC** to the primary key declaration. With a descending key, getting the max key will be very fast:

```
explain select max(a) from idcol;
```

However, having the data grow from higher to lower values might cause issues in HBase, I'm not sure whether this is a problem or not.

Here is yet another solution: Use the Trafodion feature that allows you to select the inserted data, showing you the inserted values right away:

```
select * from (insert into idcol(b) values (11),(12),(13)) t(a,b); 

A                     B          
--------------------  -----------

                   1           11
                   2           12
                   3           13

--- 3 row(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using "largeint generated always as identity not null" in table description. I don't want to fire new query which is select max() query after insert. I need latest rowId while inserting the row. After insert it should return row no. in the same query. like in mysql there is
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
which holds the newly inserted rowId.
Is it possible in Trafodion ?